# Retrieving files from Directory Node Js

Tags: node.js

I am using readDirSync to get the files from a Diretory. PLease find the code and error as following.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var files = fs.readdirSync('./application/models/');
for(var i in files) {
  var definition = require('../application/models/'+files[i]).Model;
  console.log('Model Loaded: ' + files[i]);
}
```

I am getting error for line number 2 .
ENOENT, No such file or directory './application/models/'    at Object.readdirSync  (fs.js:376:18)

I have application/models on the same dir. I already checked for '/application/models/' and
'application/models/' but failed. I can see the same thing running on server.

Please help

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `process.chdir(__dirname)`

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If you are using relative path when calling `readdirSync`, make sure it is relative to `process.cwd()`.
However, **"require" should be relative to the current script.**

For example, given the following structure

```
server.js (node process)
/lib/importer.js (the current script)
/lib/application/models/
```

you may need to write *importer.js* as:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var files = fs.readdirSync('./lib/application/models/');
for (var i in files) {
  var definition = require('./application/models/' + files[i]).Model;
  console.log('Model Loaded: ' + files[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Have you tried the following?

```
var files = fs.readdirSync(__dirname+'/application/models/');
```

Comment: yes I tried the same. it also gave me the error.. No such file or directory '/home/vikas/project-admin/includes/application/models/'

Comment: Could it be because the permissions?