# Getting empty array in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am reading a folder of images and want to get images name. But the problem here is I am getting empty array in response whereas I have checked by console I should get array of files name. Where am I going wrong?

```
app.get("/getImages",function(req,res){
    var folderName = './multiuploads/';
    var new_files   = [];     
    fs.readdir(folderName, (err, files) => {        
        for(var j=0;j<files.length;j++){
            console.log(files[j]) // this is giving me name of files
            new_files.push(files[j]);   // but this is not working                   
        }       
      }); 
      console.log(new_files); // this is coming blank
      res.send(new_files);

})
```

I am using this api to read image files from folder but the problem is that new_files array is still empty even though folder has some images.

Comment: Shouldn't **console.log** be inside `fs.readdir()` to get the results correctly.

Comment: In this instance, `fs.readdir()` is the asynchronous call and `res.send()` is the "return".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fs.readdir` is an asynchronous function which means the `callback` part will be executed sometime in the future (after directory reading is done).

Callback part:

```
(err, files) => {        
        for(var j=0;j<files.length;j++){
            console.log(files[j]) // this is giving me name of files
            new_files.push(files[j]);   // but this is not working                   
        }       
      });
```

so the code after this part is executed first which is:

```
console.log(new_files); // this is coming blank
res.send(new_files);
```

At this time `new_files` is empty because `callback` body is not executed yet. When the `callback` part is executed your program finishes there. So you wrote:

```
1
2
3
```

but it is running in this order (bbecause 2 is an async operation and JS doesn't block code execution, just jumps and run the next available code):

```
1
3
2
```

**PS (solution):**

```
app.get("/getImages",function(req,res){
    var folderName = './multiuploads/';
    var new_files   = [];     
    fs.readdir(folderName, (err, files) => {        
        for(var j=0;j<files.length;j++){
            console.log(files[j]) // this is giving me name of files
            new_files.push(files[j]);
            console.log('This line runs second');
            res.send(new_files);                 
        }       
      }); 
      console.log('This line runs first');
})
```

Comment: so what will be the solution for this writing send request inside readdir ( just after for loop)  can do the work but i dnt think it's gud.. Can u suggest in this?

Comment: As other guys said you should move any code which you want to run after reading directory into callback body (right after the loop).

Answer (score 3):

This is an async issue, try placing code after the `for` block but within the `readdir` callback:

```
app.get("/getImages",function(req,res){
var folderName = './multiuploads/';
var new_files   = [];     
fs.readdir(folderName, (err, files) => {        
    for(var j=0;j<files.length;j++){
        console.log(files[j]) 
        new_files.push(files[j]);                    
    }   
    console.log(new_files); 
    res.send(new_files);
  }); 
})
```

`readdir` callback is async, and therefor your `console.log` and `res.send` are executing before it finishes its operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `readdirSync`. Here is the link in case you need example [Retrieving files from Directory Node Js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401340/retrieving-files-from-directory-node-js)